# Reading 2D barcode using Passkit Library

Tags: ios, passkit

Currently i am trying to develop an iOS app for reading various 2D barcode & i have seen Passkit Library is able to read following bar code (PDF417, Aztec, QR).

So is it possible to create such kind of app using Passkit library ?

If possible, what are the methods for reading & extracting information from these bar codes?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the zBar SDK with good success.

- It is able to read QR codes and many kinds of bar codes.
- It was very fast at detecting and decoding images with the camera.
- It is available to install via CocoaPods (www.cocoapods.org) which makes it very easy to install and get started.

Comment: yes i have checked that but while decoding PDF417...the performance is not brilliant and it is still in alpha stage. Is there any other open source framework available

Comment: For QR codes i found the performance to be very good compared to other frameworks. Assumed bars would also be ok.  The version is 1.3.1 for iOS - stable with many apps using it. . Sure that's the one you tried? There are others, but I only did a quick evaluation before choosing zbar. Perhaps someone else will suggest another.

Comment: ...hopefully Apple has hinted for Barcode scanning API in WWDC...finger crossed :)

Comment: We have developed a fast and accurate PDF417 scanning SDK for iOS. Although it's not open-source, it is available for free for non-commercial purposes. http://pdf417.mobi